# Array to string conversion when trying to apply auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 and I wanted to apply Middleware `auth` for authenticating `admin` routes prefix:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class,'index']);
});
```

But now I get this error:

> ErrorException **Array to string conversion**

But as soon as I remove `middleware(['auth'])->` from the route, the error will be gone and shows Blade properly.

So what's going wrong here? How can I apply Middleware `auth` to this route group properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should either be

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    // routes
});
```

OR

```
Route::middleware('auth')->prefix('admin')->group(function() {
   // routes
});
```

Comment: In case someone is using Jetstream and Spatie Permissions then the syntax would be ```Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified',
    'role:Editor|Admin|SuperAdmin'
])->group(function () {});
```